# Mongodb how to return duplicate/non-distinct

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My query is working well, except that when I feed the $in an array which contains several duplicate members the **query returns distinct values only**. I wish to return all results regardless if they are distinct or duplicate. here is my query:

```
var ids = ["5648e64c0a3690ce57c0ada2","5648e64c0a3690ce57c0ada2","5648e64c0a3690ce57c0ada2","5648e64c0a3690ce57c0ada2"];
var sessionUsers =
    yield new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        users.col.aggregate([
                {
                    $match: {
                        '_id': {
                            '$in': ids // <-- ids is an array which may or may not contain duplicate ids
                        }
                    }
                            },
                {
                    $project: {
                        _id: 1,
                        pic: 1,
                        name: '$profile.name'
                    }
                }
            ],
            function (err, res) {
                if (err === null)
                    resolve(res);
                reject(err);
            });
    });
```

user document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5648e64c0a3690ce57c0ada2"),
    "pic" : "karl.png",
    "profile" : {
        "name" : "Karl Morrison"
    }
}
```

What is currently being returned:

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5648e64c0a3690ce57c0ada2"),
    "pic" : "karl.png",
    "name" : "Karl Morrison"
}]
```

I wish to return the following (there are 4 elements in the `ids` array):

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5648e64c0a3690ce57c0ada2"),
    "pic" : "karl.png",
    "name" : "Karl Morrison"
},{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5648e64c0a3690ce57c0ada2"),
    "pic" : "karl.png",
    "name" : "Karl Morrison"
},{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5648e64c0a3690ce57c0ada2"),
    "pic" : "karl.png",
    "name" : "Karl Morrison"
},{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5648e64c0a3690ce57c0ada2"),
    "pic" : "karl.png",
    "name" : "Karl Morrison"
}]
```

Comment: Can you provide a specific example of what you're talking about? It shouldn't matter if the `$in` value contains duplicates.

Comment: @JohnnyHK It's the output I'm wanting to contain duplicates! The input is fine and is working!

Comment: @JohnnyHK Updated :)

Comment: Ah, well that's a pretty odd thing to want to do. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is should not be possible, because aggregation does not aggregate a single document multiple times.

Even if there was a way to do it, that would not be the best way of doing things because it would create unnecessary network traffic, since the same document would be transferred from mongodb to your application multiple times.

I suggest fetching the document as distinct and duplicating it in your application code, if you have to.